# Elasticsearch 6.2 - Completion Suggester for long texts

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, autocomplete, elasticsearch-6

I want to be able to search and suggest through long texts.
Below is my input string:

**Clinical Support Specialist Medical Staff**

If I search for **clin** or **supp** or **spe** or ***med*** or **st** it should give the results as the above string.

Also searches could be like ***clinical sup*** or ***specialist medi***

Below is the mappings I create for the field:

```
description: {
  type: 'completion',
  analyzer: 'simple',
  preserve_separators: true,
  preserve_position_increments: true,
  contexts: {
    name: 'company',
    type: 'category',
    path: 'company',  
  }
}
```

And below is the search body:

```
descSuggestor: {
  prefix: searchTerm,
  completion: {
    field: 'description'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not specify the elastic search version, or the environment you are trying to write your search query. However, you would be able to do that with regular expression in Kibana. For example, in the Dev tools of Kibana, you could write something like:

```
GET utilization_aggregation_2018/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp" : {"name": "supp.*"}
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using Elasticsearch 6.2 on AWS and this is being used by a Node.js REST Api which is queried by an Angular App.